# Issue with cookies popup in selenium

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code in which there are several small issues i would need your help to fix:

```
import openpyxl
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

excel_spreadsheet = "companies_scraping.xlsx"
web_adress = "https://infonet.fr/entreprises/liste-des-codes-naf-ape/01-culture-et-production-animale-chasse-et-services-annexes/"

def init_workbook():
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active

    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value="company_name")
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2, value="CEO")
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=3, value="APE_code")
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=4, value="department")
    worksheet.cell(row=1, column=5, value="creation_date")

    workbook.save(excel_spreadsheet)
    return workbook

def init_driver():
    options = Options()
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
    options.add_argument('--disable-default-apps')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chromedriver_path = 'chromedriver' # Replace with the path to your Chromedriver executable
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    return driver

def scrape_companies_info(driver, workbook):
    worksheet = workbook.active
    try:
        company_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/a")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    i = 2
    for company_name in company_names:
        worksheet.cell(row=i, column=1, value=company_name.text)
        i += 1
    workbook.save(excel_spreadsheet)

def scraping(driver, workbook):
    driver.get(web_adress)
    try:
        links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='mb-1']/a")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    try:
        # time.sleep(10)
        cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]')))
        cookies_button.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    for link in links:
        link.click()
        scrape_companies_info(driver, workbook)
        driver.back()
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 30)")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # workbook = init_workbook()
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_spreadsheet)
    driver = init_driver()
    scraping(driver, workbook)
```

most important issue: the web_address that I load takes a few seconds before displaying a "accept cookies" pop up. I try to wait for it in my scraping function, but it always passes the `WebDriverWait` condition before the button appears. Then an error is thrown because i think it tries to click on the button while it is not available. I managed to fix it with a time.sleep but I would rather use the `WebDriverWait` class.
Plus, if possible, it would be nice to be able to start scraping while waiting for the cookies popup, as it does not annoy me to scrap the first entries.

the company_names i try to write in my excel file in scrape_companies_info function are not saved in my excel file for whatever reason... (i just have the column names)

To be able to click the links in my scraping function, i keep scrolling down by 30 pixels at every looprun. It is the only way i found. Is there a more efficient/general way ?

I would really appreciate if you gave me advise/best practice to follow on these several issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments about your problems:

1. Cookies box is not a real problem, you can scrape even if it is open.
2. Saving scraped data is a piece of cake if you use a dictionary to store data and the `pandas` library to export data to csv.
3. If you want to scroll to a specific `element` in the page, the best way is to use `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', element)`

Below is the code to scrape company names, CEOs, etc.

```
driver.get(web_adress)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='mb-1']/a")))
links = [{'name':link.text, 'url':link.get_attribute('href')} for link in links]

for i,link in enumerate(links):
    
    print(f'({i+1}/{len(links)}) ' + link['name'] + ' '*99, end='\r')
    driver.get(link['url'])
    
    if i == 0:
        # initialize dictionary to store data
        header = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-company-header div[class*=col-md][class*=text]')))
        header = [column_name.text for column_name in header]
        data = {key:[] for key in header}

    for j,key in enumerate(header):
        # scrape data in column j+1 ("+1" because the css selector indexing starts from 1, while python indexing starts from 0)
        column_j = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#search-company-table-body div[class*=row] > div:nth-child({j+1})')))
        cell_values = [cell.text for cell in column_j]
        data[key] += cell_values
```

The complete execution took 3 minutes and 45 seconds, but a lot ot time is "wasted" by the command `cell.text` since it is executed hundreds of times. To speed up the code you can replace the definition of `cell_values` with a javascript command

```
driver.execute_script("var result = [];" +
                      "var all = arguments[0];" +
                      "for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {" +
                      "    result.push(all[i].innerText);" +
                      "} " +
                      " return result;", column_j)
```

By using this the code execution took 1 minute and 48 seconds, saving almost 2 minutes!

Finally, you can save data in a csv by running

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('companies_scraping.csv', index=False)
```

and if you print `df` you will get

[image]

As a final note, since the webpages you want to scrape aren't dynamic, we can use simpler and faster alternatives than Selenium, such as BeautifulSoup. What it does is simply to download the html code and build a tree which we can navigate. Here is the code, which executed in just 38 seconds.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://infonet.fr/entreprises/liste-des-codes-naf-ape/01-culture-et-production-animale-chasse-et-services-annexes/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
links = soup.select("li[class=mb-1] > a")

for i,link in enumerate(links):
    
    print(f'({i+1}/{len(links)}) ' + link.text.replace('\n','') + ' '*99, end='\r')
    url = 'https://infonet.fr' + link['href'].strip()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    
    if i == 0:
        header = soup2.select('#search-company-header div[class*=col-md][class*=text]')
        header = [column_name.text for column_name in header]
        data = {key:[] for key in header}
    
    column = soup2.select('#search-company-table-body div[class*=row] > div:nth-child(1)')
    data[header[0]] += [cell_value.text.strip() for cell_value in column]

    column = soup2.select('#search-company-table-body div[class*=row] > div:nth-child(2)')
    data[header[1]] += [cell_value.text.split(':')[-1].strip() for cell_value in column]

    column = soup2.select('#search-company-table-body div[class*=row] > div:nth-child(3) > span:not([class])')
    data[header[2]] += [cell_value.text for cell_value in column]

    column = soup2.select('#search-company-table-body div[class*=row] > div:nth-child(4)')
    data[header[3]] += [cell_value.text.strip().split('\n')[-1].strip() for cell_value in column]

    column = soup2.select('#search-company-table-body div[class*=row] > div:nth-child(5)')
    data[header[4]] += [cell_value.text.split(':')[-1].strip() for cell_value in column]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('companies_scraping.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: amazing ! thank you brother, i will study this